# Regex for Adobe Analytics page URL string

Tags: regex, adobe-analytics

I want to build a segment in Adobe Analytics that matches help pages. The help page urls all have a six figure number between two colons as part of the string.

The rest of the string is inconsistent. So i am trying to match any characters then `:123456:` then any characters.

I have tried various regex in Adobe Analytics segment builder. The below expression is the one that i think is most likely to work.

```
^.*:[0-9]{1,6}:.*$
```

I am expecting an Adobe Analytics report that pulls in pages that have `:123456:` in the URL string.

Thanks!

Comment: Does AA allow regex? Can you share a link to the relevant documentation?

Comment: Regex is allowed under match in filters. Which is why I am trying to build a segment. Not sure if there is a better AA way. (can you tell i'm a GA user really).

Comment: [This page](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/user/t_reports_filter_options.html) says regex is not supported, just some "addvanced" (special chars). No character classes, no limiting quantifiers.

Comment: The only place Adobe currently allows full regex is in Classification Rule Builder. So, you can create classifications for your page names with a regex that matches pages for that, and then look at the classification report. Not sure if this will work for your ultimate needs, but is the closest you are going to get I think, short of exporting data and manually filtering.